# using zend_soap_autoDiscover in codeIgniter

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, codeigniter

I install zend_framework on my CodeIgniter and load the "Zend/Soap/AutoDiscover".
Now I want to add function to autoDiscover and generated WSDL for it. this is what have I done:

```
class Api extends CI_Controller {

public function update_profile() {


    $this->load->library('zend');
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Soap/AutoDiscover');

    $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover();
    $autodiscover->addFunction( 'hello' );
    $autodiscover->handle();
}

public function hello() {
    return "Hello world";
}
```

}

What should I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover` expects simple global functions and not method names in the `addFunction` method. If you poke around the stacktrace you will se that the parameter you add will be checked against this down the line (just before throwing exception):

```
if (!is_string($function) || !function_exists($function)) {
    // exception is thrown here
}
```

What you could use instead is the [`setClass`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.autodiscovery.html#zend.soap.autodiscovery.class) method. With this you can expose every public method of a class. For this you might find it more feasible to define a different class other then a constructor that does the real work and if you have a controller then just delegate to the service class from there.